# Определение видимости отрезка

Tags: c++, алгоритм, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

дано `N` отрезков на плоскости с началом координат в `(0, 0)` соответственно, расположение которых может быть абсолютно любым

последний отрезок назовём красным.

необходимо определить - видим ли красный отрезок из точки `(0, 0)` или он заслонён (прикрыт другими отрезками/отрезком).

для наглядности картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

здесь видно, 
что если 1 или 2 красные - то их видно из `(0, 0)`
если же красные это 3 или 4 - то не видно

собственно, моё решение (O(N)) следующее:

обозначим через `red` красный (последний) отрезок,
через `red.start` и `red.end` обозначим соответсвующие концы красного, тогда, если хотя бы один из отрезков

`(0, 0), (red.start)` и `(0, 0), (red.end)` НЕ пересекает какой-нибудь НЕ красный отрезок, то он видим из начала координат, иначе НЕ видим.

Тоесть, задача сводится к корректному определению пересечения отрезков.

вобщем, реализовал - всё работает как надо (могу показать код если интересно).

Интересует, какие есть другие алгориты работающие, например, за логарифмическое время ? 
Или за линейное но с другим подходом ?

**edit**

оказалось, что данный алгоритм не корректен, и он не учитывает случай, когда левые и правые части красного отрезка закрыты а середина видна

Comment: элементарно же приводится пример, когда два коротких черных отрезка заслоняют концы красного, а середина красного - видна

Comment: @Igor причём тут этот пример ?

Comment: @Igor хотите сказать, что этот пример мой алгоритм не учитывает ?

Comment: да, хочу сказать

Comment: Задача не допускает "правильного ответа" пока не уточнено, является ли запрос по точкам *массовым*. То есть будет ли для одного и того же неизменного набора отрезков решаться задача для нескольких (многих) разных точек наблюдения.

Comment: @AnT нет, точка наблюдения только одна - это (0, 0)

Comment: @AnT ну, в общем случае точка наблюдения может быть произвольной, от чего алгоритм не должен измениться, но в этой задаче эта точка - начало координат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильный алгоритм:

пересечь черные отрезки с линией красного и оставить те части черных отрезков, которые находятся в одной полуплоскости (граница - линия красного отрезка) с точкой (0,0). Спроецировать все оставшиеся черные куски на линию красного отрезка. Если красный отрезок полностью перекрыт (анализ объединения отрезков, лежащих на одной прямой) - он не видим, в противном случае - видим.

*Уточнение от @AnT:*

ортогональная проекция здесь не подходит. Нужна проекция вдоль луча из точки (0, 0).

*Так, мое уточнение:*

"Оставшимися" будем называть части черных отрезков лежащие внутри треугольника образованного красным отрезком и отрезками, соединяющими точку (0,0) с концами красного отрезка.

*Update*

иллюстрация к комментарию @ampawd про ортогональную проекцию на ось Х.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А про "сумму частей проекций" Вы сами можете привести контр-пример - сумма частей будет больше проекции красного, а дырки все равно останутся. Нужно именно *объединение*.

*Update 2*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зеленые куски - это и есть проекции черных кусков (попавших внутрь оранжево-красного треугольника) на красный отрезок. Если красный отрезок полностью перекрыт зелеными, то он не виден.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55670/discussion-on-answer-by-igor---).